# Display JSON data in dialog with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using `Vue.js`, **how do you use** `axios GET` **to display the response in a dialog?**

I've tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <template>
        <label>Protocol</label> Display protocol details from json
        <div class="text-xs-center">
            <br>
        </div>
    </template>
<script>
export default {
    dialog3: false
    created() {
        let self = this
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/ap/device')
            .then(function(response) {
                self.fDModelName(response.data.result)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.result))
            })
    },
    methods: {
        fDModelName: function(message) {
            console.log("inside")
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `v-if="chip === true"`, This seems wrong? Is chips an object of true, false values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a data object where you have content as a key. On component created, you can assign it to the component's content value.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ content }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            content: []
        }
    },
    created () {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/ap/device')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.content = response.data.result   
            })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Im having nested objects in an json,how can i use it in {{content}}?            The json is as below,in that i need temperature value and type value         "sDataModel":{
 
   "name":"",
   "sDetails":[{
       "temperature":"Hot",
       "type":""
      }]
  }

Comment: You can access name using {{ content.name }} and if you want to get the temperature, you can use {{ content.sDetails[0]. temperature  }}

Since sDetails is a list, you can loop through sDetails using v-for.

<li v-for="detail in content.sDetails">{{detail.temperature}} {{detail.type}}</li>